# How to exit properly from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the following:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
...
def method1
  @data=@might_be_awesome_might_not
  validate_me
  do_some_other_cool_stuff
  render json: { 'Success!' }
end

def validate_me
  return if @data == 'Awesome'
  render json: { 'Crap! Not Valid' }
end
...
end
```

I'd like to know how to properly exit after rendering the error so that rails doesn't complain about two renders. I tried 
    render json: { 'Crap! Not Valid' } && exit

That broke my test suite. It doesn't break tests with an error, they just don't run. BTW this is just an example never run, likely syntactic issues, code to demonstrate my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `render` through `callback`:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_data, :validate_me
  ...
  def method1
    do_some_other_cool_stuff
    render json: { 'Success!' }
  end

  private

  def set_data
    @data = @might_be_awesome_might_not
  end

  def validate_me
    render json: { 'Crap! Not Valid' } unless @data == 'Awesome'
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: So the problem with that is it returns only from the validate_me still leaving  two renders in the same action. it doesn't exit from the controller method1. I could change validate_me method to return false, and then return again if validate_me is false in method1. It just doesn't feel clean.

Comment: Your implementation was close enough to get me to a break through. The before_action does allow the render to exit implicitly. For some reason, the explicit return breaks that behavior, so don't do that. Just render, don't render && return. I ended up moving all the logic into a before_action and removing the explicit return altogether. That worked for me.